# Deploy no Heroku aplicação PYTHON/DJANGO dando erro

Tags: python, django

Fiz uma alteração no auth padrão do django e meu projeto está funcionando corretamente porém quando eu dou git push heroku master e seguidamente utilizo o comando  heroku run python manage.py migrate para criar o meu banco de dados e ele da o erro:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration
>   accounts.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexis nt parent node
>   ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length')

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Voce esta fazendo makemigrations antes do migrate?

Comment: Bom pelo que eu saiba não necessito dar um makemigrations no heroku apenas o migrate para criação do banco

Comment: Eu me refereia a makemigrations local. Veja o a resposta e os comentários [dessa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables), talvez possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o seu makemigrations tenha criado o "0008_alter_user_username_max_length"  na pasta do app auth que não é versionado junto com seu projeto. Então para o heroku a dependência da sua migração realmente não existe.

Para resolver aconselharia você a estender o app de auth. Criar seu próprio modelo de usuário e configurá-lo como o padrão.
No settings por exemplo:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

E no models:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    height = models.FloatField()
    ...
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth', 'height']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model